# Не могу понять , как правильно мне передать значение переменной window2 в spawntwo

Tags: vue.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      play: false,
      active: {'1':0,'2':0,'3':0},
      prepare: false,
      spawns: {
        window2: true,
        window3: false
      },
      spawnone: true,
      spawntwo: true,
      spawnthri: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSelectone(windowID) {
      if (this.spawnone !== true) {
        return false
      }

      console.log(windowID)
      this.active[windowID] = true
      setTimeout(() => this.prepare = true, 6000)
      setTimeout(() => this.$emit("play", windowID), 8000)
    },
    onSelecttwo(windowID) {
      if (this.spawntwo !== true) {
        return false
      }

      console.log(windowID)
      this.active[windowID] = true
      setTimeout(() => this.prepare = true, 6000)
      setTimeout(() => this.$emit("play", windowID), 8000)
    },
    onSelectthri(windowID) {
      if (this.spawnthri !== true) {
        return false
      }

      console.log(windowID)
      this.active[windowID] = true
      setTimeout(() => this.prepare = true, 6000)
      setTimeout(() => this.$emit("play", windowID), 8000)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.Window-1 {
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.Window-1:before {
  background: url("/img/window-1-bg.png") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.Window-1:not(.active):hover:after {
  background: rgba(0, 44, 202, 0.2);
}

.Window-2 {
  height: 50vh;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Window-2:before {
  background: url("/img/window-2-bg.png") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.Window-2:not(.active):not(.gray):hover:after {
  background: rgba(174, 0, 31, 0.2);
}

.Window-3 {
  height: 50vh;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.Window-3:before {
  background: url("/img/window-3-bg.png") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.Window-3:not(.active):not(.gray):hover:after {
  background: rgba(177, 128, 0, 0.2);
}

.window {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition: width .3s, height .3s;
  transition: width .3s, height .3s;
}

.window.active {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh !important;
  z-index: 3 !important;
}

.window:before, .window:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.window:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
  transition: transform .3s;
  transition: transform .3s, -webkit-transform .3s;
}

.window.gray:before {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
          filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.window:not(.active):not(.gray):hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}

.window:after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s, opacity 1.3s;
  transition: background-color .3s, opacity 1.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, .7s;
          transition-delay: 0s, .7s;
}

.window > .wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.window > .wrap > .title {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: FuturaMediumC, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 6.66667vh;
  line-height: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s, -webkit-transform .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s, -webkit-transform .3s;
  transition: transform .3s, opacity .3s;
  transition: transform .3s, opacity .3s, -webkit-transform .3s;
}

.window > .wrap > .title.title-2 {
  font-family: FuturaBookC, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 3.33333vh;
  line-height: 3.7963vh;
}

.window > .wrap:hover > .title {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
          transform: scale(1.15);
}

.window > .wrap > .hr {
  display: block;
  width: 65%;
  height: 0.18519vh;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 4.25926vh;
  margin-bottom: 3.33333vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

.window > .wrap-lock {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.window > .wrap-lock > .icon {
  display: block;
  width: 9.25926vh;
  height: 9.25926vh;
  background: url("/img/spawn-lock-icon.png") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 9.25926vh 9.25926vh;
}

.window > .wrap-lock > .title {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: FuturaBookC, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 3.88889vh;
  line-height: 4.44444vh;
  margin-left: 2.59259vh;
}

.window.Window-2 > .wrap > .title, .window.Window-3 > .wrap > .title {
  font-size: 5.55556vh;
}

.window.Window-2 > .wrap > .title.title-2, .window.Window-3 > .wrap > .title.title-2 {
  font-size: 2.77778vh;
  line-height: 3.14815vh;
}

.window.Window-2 > .wrap > .hr, .window.Window-3 > .wrap > .hr {
  margin-top: 2.22222vh;
  margin-bottom: 2.40741vh;
}

.window.active > .wrap > .title,
.window.active > .wrap > .hr, .window.active:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.window > .loading-screen {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .7s, background-color 2.4s;
  transition: opacity .7s, background-color 2.4s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1.6s, 3.2s;
          transition-delay: 1.6s, 3.2s;
}

.window > .loading-screen > .logo {
  display: block;
  width: 32.40741vh;
  height: 12.96296vh;
  background: url("/img/logo.png") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 32.40741vh 12.96296vh;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5vh;
  left: 7.31481vh;
}

.window > .loading-screen > .text {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Montserrat-SemiBold, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 4.44444vh;
  line-height: 5.46296vh;
  text-shadow: 0 0.18519vh 1.48148vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: absolute;
  right: 8.42593vh;
  bottom: 9.90741vh;
}

.window > .loading-screen > .logo,
.window > .loading-screen > .text {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.window.active > .loading-screen {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 4;
}

.window.prepare > .loading-screen > .logo,
.window.prepare > .loading-screen > .text {
  opacity: 0;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: FuturaMediumC;
  src: url("/fonts/FuturaMediumC.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: FuturaBookC;
  src: url("/fonts/FuturaBookC.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Montserrat-SemiBold;
  src: url("/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf");
}

#app {
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

#app.play {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" :class="{play:play}">
    <div :class="['Window-1 window', {active:active[1], prepare:prepare}]" @click="onSelectone(1)">
       <div class="wrap">
         <div class="title">Появиться на точке<br> последнего выхода</div>
         <div class="hr"></div>
         <div class="title title-2">Вы не потеряете ничего</div>
       </div>
       <div class="loading-screen">
         <div class="logo"> </div>
         <div class="text">Загрузка...</div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div :class="['Window-2 window', {gray:!spawns.window2, active:active[2], prepare:prepare}]" @click="onSelecttwo(2)">
       <div v-if="spawns.window2" class="wrap">
         <div class="title">Появиться в своём доме</div>
         <div class="hr"> </div>
         <div class="title title-2">Содержимое инвентаря будет сброшено (кроме одежды)</div>
       </div>
       <div v-else class="wrap-lock">
         <div class="icon"> </div>
         <div class="title">Для разблокировки возможности появления<br> в доме необходимо его купить</div>
       </div>
       <div class="loading-screen">
         <div class="logo"> </div>
         <div class="text">Загрузка...</div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div :class="['Window-3 window', {gray:!spawns.window3, active:active[3], prepare:prepare}]" @click="onSelectthri(3)" >
       <div v-if="spawns.window3" class="wrap">
         <div class="title">Появиться на территории фракции</div>
         <div class="hr"></div>
         <div class="title title-2">Содержимое инвентаря будет сброшено (кроме одежды)</div>
       </div>
       <div v-else="" class="wrap-lock">
         <div class="icon"> </div>
         <div class="title">Для разблокировки возможности появления<br> в фракции необходимо в неё вступить</div>
       </div>
       <div class="loading-screen">
         <div class="logo"> </div>
         <div class="text">Загрузка...</div>
       </div>
    </div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onSelectone(windowID) {
if (this.spawns.window2 !== true) {
return false
}

```js
onSelectone(windowID) {
      if (this.spawns.window2 !== true) {
        return false
      }
```

`